# 403 Error handling

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, http-status-code-403

I have a basic web application written in PHP I am looking to secure, app is located on a local web server.

When using the following url string :

http://localhost/test/index.php%20and%20substring(database(%20),1,1)=%22a%22

The application is outputting the following error message:

[image: 403]

I would like the web page to display a message like "URL Provided does not exist"

I created a .htaccess file and dropped it into the directory containing the following:

[image]

But I am still facing the error providing the file structure, the server I am using and the port it is communicating on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For allowing `ErrorDocument` you need to set `AllowOverride` to `All`. For example, this is my **virtualhost** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias php.local
    ServerAlias sub.php.local

    LogLevel debug

    DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/php

    <Directory /var/www/projects/php>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

You can also set `AllowOverride` to `FileInfo` for using `ErrorDocument`.

See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html